# Parsing Word Document using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have to write a powershell script that can parse word document. Specifically, it has to read text from textboxes and store it in a variable. I know how to read text e.g. from a paragraph, but I don't know how to deal with textboxes. I would appreciate a sample.

Here is a part of my code:

```
    $Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $False
    $datasheet = $word.Documents.Open($files[$i].FullName)
    $value = ....?
```

Here is a screenshot of the box I need to read from:

[image]

Comment: `TextBoxes` should be accessible via the `$datasheet.Shapes` collection

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you very much. I tried $text = $datasheet.Shapes[1].range.Text, but the variable is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate the contents of the `Shapes` collection and filter for shapes of the [`msoTextBox` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) (17):

```bsh
$datasheet.Shapes |Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 17} |ForEach-Object {
    # copy $_.TextFrame.TextRange.Text to wherever you need it in here 
    # $_.TextFrame.TextRange is a range object like any other (useful if you need formatting details or raw XML for example)
}
```

Comment: Thank you again. I am still doing something wrong. The execution never comes inside the loop. Moreover, when I removed the condition Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 17}, it still does not enter the loop. For some reason the collection is empty. I added a picture of the box to my question. Maybe it is not a Shape??

Comment: @DavidShochet `$datasheet.Shapes.Count` is `0`? And you're certain you've loaded/opened the document as `$datasheet`? If so, I'm afraid I have no idea :)

Comment: No, it is not 0. And now this loop $datasheet.Shapes |ForEach-Object { works, but $datasheet.Shapes |Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 17} |ForEach-Object { does not work. As before, the execution never enters the loop.

Comment: Double-check yourself and your calls by making MSWord tell you what the deal is. While in an open doc, fire off the Macro Recorder, use the UI to click thru the doc, export the VBA and compare that you what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidShochet Ahh, so it's a _different_ kind of shape. Try `$datasheet.Shapes |% Type` to enumerate all the shape types present in the document

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Thanks, this moves me closer. I found there are shapes 13 and 6 there. I tried both, and I could loop through those shapes, but it seems that the text is returned as empty: $txt = $_.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

Comment: @DavidShochet take a look at the [`MsoShapeType` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype), looks like 6 is a group - probably it'll contain the actual text box

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Unfortunately, it does not tell how the msoGroup can be parsed...